# ng не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: angular-cli

Всем здрасте! Кто-нить сталкивался с такой пролемой в Angular-CLI, после установки и вызова "ng" ошибка - "ng не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."? В PATH путь к npm прописан.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

Angular cli надо устоновить глобально

windows:

```
npm install -g "@angular/cli"
```

macOs/Linux:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: Вроде на винде тоже можно без кавычек?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте прописать PATH в Свойства системы-> Дополнительно -> Переменные среды
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin или
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin

Comment: Была такая проблема. Решить её можно, если вышесказанное не помогло, переустановив или обновив nodejs и npm. Зачастую это просто глюк npm.

Comment: Я устанавливал так: npm install -g "@angular/cli"

Comment: Всё равно ng давало ошибку

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая проблема. В итооге оказалось, что npm установился в programfiles, а ангуляр в C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm.

Просто скопировал все из roaming\npm и вставил в C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm и все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить его

```
npm install -g @nrwl/cli
```